# Android realm gradle plugin issue

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

So I have a project which uses a realm in it. I'm getting an issue no matter what version of the plugin I use. The issue is `unable to instantiate appComponantFactory`, `MultiDexApplication` class not found, etc.

When I remove the realm Gradle plugin and run the app, the app runs perfectly without any issue like class not found an exception.

I searched on the internet and no one posted about this. By the way, the project uses Kotlin (I'm not sure whether it make a problem with the realm plugin)

Also is there any other option available to add realm in my app except using the realm Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `multiDexEnabled true` in your `app/build.gradle` file.

Like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ur.app.package"
        multiDexEnabled true  // <<-- add this

        //....all other stuff

    }

    //all other stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(1) Please add `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` in your app/build.gradle file

(2) Add Application class and add it into the manifest file

```
class ApplicationClass : MultiDexApplication() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    MultiDex.install(this)
    mInstance = this
    val builder = VmPolicy.Builder()
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())
    val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
}

companion object {
    private var mInstance: ApplicationClass? = null
}}
```

(3) Add Application class into Manifest file's  tag

```
 <application
    android:name=".utils.ApplicationClass" </application>
```

Comment: There is no reason to set strict mode to permit all and you shouldn't be doing that either